# Emoji do not show up in Chromium, render as empty boxes

Tags: debian, fonts, chrome, emoji

When I try to view something like the [Link Emoji ()](https://emojipedia.org/link/) what I see rendered in my browser is a empty box. I see some web services are [now using these glyphs.](https://github.com/Troglodyne-Internet-Widgets/tCMS/issues/156)

This is what it looks like currently,

[image: Empty box icons]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a font that can render Emojis. [You can find the font list in the Chromium source code here](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/99314be8152e688bafbbf9a615536bdbb289ea87/content/test/data/font_src_local_matching.html#L6)

On Debian based distros, you can add the preferred [Google Noto Font](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) with,

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-noto-color-emoji
killall chromium # restart chrome
```

Comment: Thanks! this was exactly what I was looking for 

Comment: @Don np, if it helepd upvote the question and answer. =)

Comment: doh! done, and done!

Comment: And a slightly less brutal restart: in the URL bar, type `chrome://restart` ;)